# Why angle of parallel lines is not same? opencv c++

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I detected lane lines in opencv and calculated their angles (which are shown by read lines in the image), although they look almost the same angle, the angle calculated by the program shows quiet a difference with left line always greater than right.

I am using arctan(slope) to find angles.

Is is due to the fact that y-axis in MAT matrix is inverted?

I am trying to detect the difference in the lane line angles to detect turns and straight road. How can I do achieve my goal? which I can not right now because lines do not have same(but opposite) angle on the straight road.

Below is the image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rym25.jpg)

Comment: Because they are not parallel in perspective view.

Comment: Pease clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Specifically your relevant code and image examples would be helpful.

Comment: "Is is due to the fact that y-axis in MAT matrix is inverted?" No. Simply put, your lines are not as similar of an angle as you think. Additionally, If the left was -30 and the right was 30, this wouldn't mean they are parallel. Perspective shifts change the angle of lines. What are you expecting them to be? The current output looks completely reasonable to me.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Ok, I dont understand the concept of perspective shift, will you elaborate a little on that, I will be very grateful.

Comment: add a sample image. Are the lines parallel in your image or only parallel in reality?

Comment: Just look at the image: the lines are clearly not parallel, they're almost perpendicular. The lines are parallel on the *ground* of course, but since the camera is not looking straight down from above, they don't appear parallel. Google image search 'perspective'; you know the concept, just maybe not used to how I used the word above. Imagine if the car was driving directly over one of the lines---that line would be straight up and down, but the other lane line would be heavily angled. The angles will only be exact opposites when the road is totally flat and the camera is *perfectly* centered.

Comment: @Micka sample image is at the bottom of the post in link. Parallel in reality, not parallel in image.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thats exxactly what I am trying to achieve. I want to detect when a lane line gets closer to 90 degree or straigth line, but the inconsistency in angles is making it harder.

Comment: For what? As it stands, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually trying to achieve* with this code? Currently you're asking for help with your attempted solution, but with no mention of the problem you're trying to solve. Also this question still has no code and is formatted badly; please read over the "How to Ask" page I linked earlier and edit your question accordingly. The easier you make your question to answer, the more & better answers you'll get.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds for steering a car. When a line gets closer to 90, steer in opposite direction to that line.

Comment: How about trying to center the intersection of the two lines? If you're more to the right, the intersection will be left of center, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of the two angles is not close to zero, because the lines are not parallel in 2D, simple as that. You are comparing angles of 2D lines in the image plane!

What you want to do is to check how close is the sum of the angles to zero, i.e. `fabs(angle1 + angle2)`. You probably also want to check if `fabs(angle1)` and `fabs(angle2)` are within a specific range.

Furthermore, you shouldn't use slopes, as the slope of a vertical line is infinity. You probably have 2D direction vectors for each line at some point. Either use `atan2(dy, dx)` to compute the angle for each line, or you could stick with the direction vectors, in the latter case adding the normalized direction vectors and comparing their angle to the vector `(0, 1)`, which is the vertical line.

Be aware that all this assumes that the camera points into the direction of the (straight) lane.